# gnuplot auto legend generation for all datasets

Tags: gnuplot, legend

I would like to know how to generate legends automatically with "option-1" plot command below. I get three curves but only one legend name i.e. only "Y0" appears.

With "option-2" I can get all legend names but I do not like this approach for large datasets.

CONTENTS of plot file:

---

```
set key autotitle columnhead

#option-1
plot "dataset" skip 1 index 0:2:1 using 1:2:(1+column(-2)) title\
     columnhead with linespoints  linecolor variable

#option-2
plot "dataset" skip 1 index 0 using 1:2 title columnhead with linespoints,\
     "" skip 1 index 1 using 1:2 title columnhead with linespoints,\
     "" skip 1 index 2 using 1:2 title columnhead with linespoints
```

---

CONTENTS OF "dataset" file:

---

## A text file

```
#index_0
X0      Y0
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4


#index_1
X1       Y1
0        2
1        3
2        4
3        5


#index_2
X2        Y2
0         3
1         4
2         5
3         6
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to cure your option-1, but you can automate option-2 for large datasets using a `for` loop:

```
N=2 # last index
plot for [i=0:N] "dataset" skip 1 index i using 1:2 title columnhead with linespoints
```

Comment: Thanks Joce! It was of great help.